# Find the limit of $\lim_{x \to 3} \frac{\ln x - \ln 3}{x - 3} $

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find the limit of:

$\lim_\limits{x \to 3} \frac{\ln x - \ln 3}{x - 3} $

For starters, I substitute $y = x - 3$.

So:  $\lim_\limits{x \to 3} \frac{\ln x - \ln 3}{x - 3} = \lim_\limits{y \to 0} \frac{\ln (y + 3) - \ln 3}{y}$

And since it's an indeterminate form, I'll use L'Hopital, so:

$\lim_\limits{y \to 0} \frac{\ln (y + 3) - \ln 3}{y} = \lim_\limits{y \to 0} \frac{d}{dy}( \ln (y+3) - \ln 3) = \lim_\limits{y \to 0} (\frac{1}{y + 3} - \frac{1}{3}) = 0$

But according to the answers, it should be: $\frac{1}{3}$. What am I missing here?

Comment: $\ln 3$ is constant

Comment: Ah, yeah, of course! Thanks... Convert to an answer so I can upvote :)

Comment: This is *the definition* of the derivative of the logarithmic function at $3$, so using l’Hôpital is just a waste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set $x-3=3y\iff x=3y+3$

$$\lim_{x\to3}\dfrac{\ln x-\ln3}{x-3}=\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\ln(3+3y)-\ln3}{3y}=\dfrac13\cdot\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+y)}y=?$$

Answer (score 2):

Compare:

$$ \left.\frac{df(x)}{dx} \right|_{x=3}  \triangleq \lim_{x\to3} {{f(x) - f(3)}\over x-3}$$

so $ L = \frac13.$ No need for LHR.

Answer (score 1):

When you do your L'Hopital, you calculate $\frac{d}{dy} \ln(y+3)-\ln(3) = \frac{1}{y+3}-\frac{1}{3}$. The derivative of $\ln(3)$ is not $\frac{1}{3}$.